# css-fix for screen jumping up and down when scroll on android-devices

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

Some bootstrap themes(not sure if it's just bootstrap) have the annoying issue when scrolling upp and down on a android-device, the screen is jumping up or down a few pixels.

If you have a android-device and for example goes to this adress: http://clapat.ro/themes/newave/ and do some scrolling, you will see what I mean (doing it in like chrome dev-tools device mode will not show the problem) When doing this on iPhone, iPad ect. I'm not having this problem at all. Someone else having this annoing issue and have any css or js-fix for it?

The device I'm using is Sony Xperia Z1 Compact and the browser is Chrome.

EDIT: I've tried a few other browers as well on android. And everything works fine there. So it just seems to be google chrome on android having this issue. Someone else having this problem to??

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it twice on my S4 using Chrome and it worked fine - is there a particular point that it jumps?